# Read file name from user input on linux terminal - JAVA

Tags: java, linux, file, terminal

I want to make a little script in JAVA to receive a file name in the linux terminal and read that file.

This is what i'm trying:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class ItauScript {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Filename: ");
        String fileName = reader.next();

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
    }
}
```

But the code doesn't compile. I get this error message:

> hello.java:10: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must
>   be caught or declared to be thrown
>           FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
>                                   ^ hello.java:13: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
>           System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());

I can open the file if i put it on hardcode on a string.
But i need to receive it as an input from the terminal.

What am i missing?

Comment: You will get the same compilation error even when you hardcode the filename. Take a look at what your IDE offers you as a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class ItauScript {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Filename: ");
    String fileName = reader.next();

    try {
       FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

       System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception (if any) here
    }
}
}
```

And as others suggested, it's very helpful to read what the IDE/Compiler tells you in case of errors ...

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

`FileNotFoundException` is a **checked** `Exception` (as is the parent class `IOException` thrown by `readLine`), modify `main` to re-throw<sup>1</sup> it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

**or** surround it with a [`try-catch` (with resources)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
    System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

<sup>1<sub>But you *should* still `close` the `bufferedReader` in a `finally`.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the possible exception. You can specify that the enclosing method `main` throws the exception, but it would be better to handle it yourself.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class ItauScript {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Filename: ");
            String fileName = reader.next();

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //TODO handle error
            return;
        }
    }
}
```